# Laptop Throttling to .5GHz & 20% Util Temporarliy

Tags: windows, laptop, cpu, gpu

My Dell Inspiron 15 7567 Gaming Laptop has been lagging in-game, for roughly 15-30 seconds and when it does, my Intel i5-7300HQ CPU throttles to .5GHz and 20% util. After that 15-30 seconds, the CPU becomes unthrottled to 3.0-3.4 GHz, and the utilization of my CPU goes back up to 75-90%. The GPU also throttles when my CPU does, but that is because the GPU is waiting on the CPU for commands (CPU bottlenecking). When the CPU throttles, the temps are very under-control and never go above 75c.

Specs:

- Laptop: 2017 Dell Inspiron 15 7567 Gaming
- CPU: Intel i5-7300HQ
- GPU: Nvidia GTX 1050 Mobile (Max-P)
- Storage:
  - C:/ Samsung 960 Evo 250GB M.2
  - D:/ Toshiba SSHD 1TB SATA
  - E:/ Western Digital My Passport X 3TB USB 3.0 HDD
- Monitor: Samsung U28E590 (4k 60hz, running at 1080p 60hz)
- RAM: SK Hynix 1x8 2400MHz DDR4

I've tried the following and the issue still occurs:

- Updating my BIOS to the latest version
- Using DDU on my GPU
- Using an older Nvidia GPU
- Defragmenting my drives
- Running 'Driver Booster 7'

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: I do not disagree with the first four actions. Can you uninstall Driver Booster?  and then install the Manufacturer's drivers from the manufacturer's website?

Comment: I could, but I don't know what drivers I would need to update/reinstall. I went through Dell for the BIOS and Nvidia for my GPU drivers.

Comment: Use the Dell Driver Update app to determine what you need. I am not a big fan of third party driver updates because they do not know as well as Dell knows what you need for Dell machines.  (Same for HP and Lenovo)

Comment: @John, I used the Dell Driver Update app to update 7 drivers (Intel HD Audio, Intel Wireless Networking and Intel HD Graphics) and after I updated my computer and restarted it, my computer is still throttling itself.